# How to Check multiple coma separated string present in list or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to search coma separated string present in list or not, like multiple string present in list or not. How to perform this operation

I tried like this

```
location = ["Bangalore", "Delhi"]
locations_list = ["Bangalore", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Uttar Pradesh"]

if any(location in str for str in locations_list ):
    print("location present in locations list")
else:
    print("location not found")
```

Comment: no its printing else part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are checking if `list` is in `str` rather than if `str` is in `list`.

Change your code as below:

```
if any(lcr in location for lcr in locations_list ):
    print("location present in locations list")
else:
    print("location not found")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in whether or not any of the elements is present, I would suggest doing it using set intersections:

```
if set(location) & set(locations_list):
    print("location present in locations list")
else:
    print("location not found")
```

EDIT:

In case you want to check if *all* locations in `location` are in `location_list`, I suggest using the set's `issubset` method:

```
if set(location).issubset(set(locations_list)):
    print("location present in locations list")
else:
    print("location not found")
```

Comment: @bexi: if it gets any matched word , it will show "location present in locations list". However, there is another unmatched word. Example, location = ["Bangalore", "Kolkata"]. It shows "location present in locations list".

Comment: @Chandan: Yes, the given code returns 'true' if at leas one location is in location_list (I thought this is what was asked). I added another bit of code to my solution which checks if *all* locations are in location_list. Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Here I give you a correct example of implementation.

```
location = ["Bangalore", "Delhi"]
locations_list = ["Bangalore", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Uttar Pradesh"]
for location in location :
    for ref in locations_list:
        if location == ref:
            print(f"{location} present in locations list")
```

This is a classic aproximation of your task. However as you know nested loops are horrible in performance.

So... I give you this a little better implementation:

```
    location = ["Bangalore", "Delhi"]
locations_list = ["Bangalore", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Hyderabad", "Uttar Pradesh"]
[print(f"{location} present in locations list") for location in location for ref in locations_list if (location == ref)]
```

In this code I've used list comprehension to improve a little the performance,but the concept is the same. Check every item in the first list and compare it to every item in the other list.

Maybe you could improve your performance adding a **continue** everytime you get a match.

I know these aren't the best way to perform that kind of search, but both of them are simple and runnable.

PD: Just to mark, I've used python 3.6+ if you want to run the codes in lower versions just remove the f before strings

Comment: Thanks a lot. so many way to solve this question. it helped me a lot.